# JVM is getting hanged for few seconds in java 6

Tags: java

After upgrading our application(Mindalign) from jdk 1.4 to jdk 1.6 , it was found that JVM often gets hanged for few seconds.

Observation:

During startup, Application does a lot of I/O operations (i.e loading xml file, sending data to Tcp/Ip socket)
There is a gap of around 2 second can be observed during these operations.

Given below is the sample logs during the issue.

Compiled with JDK1.4

```
DEBUG 14Jan30 16:33:42108  digester.xml.AbstractDigestBinder/shutdown        | loading configuration: 
DEBUG 14Jan30 16:33:42218  gs.group_server.GroupServer/shutdown              | Maximum exception occurred within the timespan is set to 0

INFO  14Jan30 16:33:53153  rr.net.ConnectionManager/MessageHandler    | [IRC] << :groupserver. RPLWHOREG
INFO  14Jan30 16:33:53153  rr.net.ConnectionManager/MessageHandler    | [IRC] << :groupserver. RPLWHOREG


Compiled with JDK1.6

DEBUG 14Feb05 14:22:45801  digester.xml.AbstractDigestBinder/shutdown        | loading configuration: 
DEBUG 14Feb05 14:22:47205  gs.group_server.GroupServer/shutdown              | Maximum exception occurred within the timespan is set to 0

DEBUG 14Feb05 14:22:54599  rr.net.ConnectionManager/MessageHandler       | [IRC] << :groupserver. RPLWHOREG
DEBUG 14Feb05 14:22:56502  rr.net.ConnectionManager/MessageHandler                | [IRC] << :groupserver. RPLWHOREG
```

Please suggest me, how to troubleshoot this issue. **strong text**

Can it be related with xms value (heap size) of java..?

Comment: Java VisualVM, which is included in the JDK, allows you to monitor the heap size (shows you detailed graphs about memory usage in the different spaces of the heap). It might help you to find out if the GC is doing some work, freezing your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use a profiler and/or VisualVM to look at what your application is doing.

Turn on garbage collection debugging to see if there is anything going on there.

Use a debugger to "pause" the application during one of these stalls and then investigate to see what it's doing or waiting for.

I don't actually see huge differences in the two timings though:

:42 to :53 is :11 difference, in the second case :47 to :54 is :07 difference. It's actually got faster...which is to be expected as the 1.6 JVM is smarter than the 1.4 one.

Comment: HI,as per my application its loading more then 2l users and pausing between 2 sec or 1 sec, currently i m using jconsole but i did't found anything meaningful for that 2 sec.